# Generating WAR and EAR artifacts inside the same Gradle project

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, war, dry, ear

Suppose that I have a Gradle web project with a standard web project layout `src/main/webapp`.

Project `myproject-web`, `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'
```

I know that I can wrap the resulting `.war` file generated by `myproject-web` inside an `.ear` if I define a secondary project (say, `myproject-ear`) which applies the `ear` plugin and references `myproject-web` as a dependency:

Project `myproject-ear`, `build.gradle`:

```
deploy project(':myproject-web')
```

I know it's a bit pointless to create an `.ear` file with only one `.war` inside (but that's how I'm required to deliver artifacts at my current job). So would it be possible to entirely skip the definition of the project `myproject-ear` and just use the `ear` plugin directly inside `myproject-web`'s build file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the ear plugin to your war project, then add the war into the ear using the following configuration:

```
ear {
    from war.outputs.files
}
```